# Will dissolved proteins pass through a 0.2 micron filter?

Tags: proteins, purification

Given that there may be exceptions, can you usually expect protein to pass through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many proteins will pass through a 0.2 micron filter. If the proteins aggregate or if they stick to the filter material because it is charged, they may not.

Barring the above, a 0.2 micron filter will allow proteins up to 200kd to pass through.  There are some proteins that are larger.

Editing with some source material.

Nice [Presentation on Pore Sizes and Membranes Here](http://web.stanford.edu/group/ees/rows/presentations/Wilf.pdf)

Graphic from that presentation:

[image]

Comment: Stanford ppt link is broken :(